# Transfer word comments to excel

Tags: vba, excel

I needed help transferring word comments to excel in a coherent manner. I've printed the comments to PDF using the print "list of markups" function in word.

[image: Here is the PDF print out of the words comments]

I basically needed a macro to convert this PDF to this result.....

[image]

Now this is just an example as other documents I have may have more than 1 comment. I needed a macro to convert multiple comments in a PDF.

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this: [ExtractCommentsToNewDoc](https://www.thedoctools.com/downloads/basComments_Extract.htm)?

Comment: This may be interesting too: [How to retrieve comments from word document using VBA](http://pharma-sas.com/how-to-retrieve-comments-from-word-document-using-vba/)